# Change cell color in SheetA when value changes in SheetB in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets: SheetA and SheetB with identical values in corresponding cells. I'm trying to change the cell color in SheetA when the value of the cell in SheetB changes. For example if cell A5 has value 10 in both sheets and I then change it to 5 in SheetB, I want the background color of the cell in SheetA to change

This is the code so far

```
function onEdit(e){
  
  var sheetsToWatch = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetA");
  var sheetsToEdit = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetB"); 
  var cell = sheetsToEdit.getActiveCell();  // checking the active cell
  var bg = '#faec15'

  for (let i = 0; i < active_sheet.length; i++) {
    if (sheetsToWatch.match(sheetsToEdit[i])) {
      sheetsToWatch.getRange(cell.getRow(), cell.getColumn()).setBackground(bg);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Did you try the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheetB = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetB_name = sheetB.getName();
  if (sheetB_name != 'SheetB') return;

  var sheetB_cell_value = e.value;
  var sheetB_cell_row = e.range.rowStart;
  var sheetB_cell_col = e.range.columnStart;
  
  var sheetA = e.source.getSheetByName('SheetA');
  var sheetA_cell = sheetA.getRange(sheetB_cell_row,sheetB_cell_col);
  var sheetA_cell_value = sheetA_cell.getValue();

  if (sheetB_cell_value != sheetA_cell_value) sheetA_cell.setBackground('#faec15');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'SheetB' ) {
    e.source.getSheetByName('SheetA').getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setBackground("#faec15");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works now. Please find my solution below

```
function onEdit() {

var sheetsToWatch = ['SheetA'];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
var row = cell.getRowIndex();
var column= cell.getColumnIndex();
var sheetName = sheet.getName();
var matchFound = false;

for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
}
if (!matchFound) return;

var sheetToEdit = ss.getSheetByName('SheetB');
var editRow = sheetToEdit.getLastRow();
var editColumn = sheetToEdit.getLastColumn();

for (var j = 1; j <= editRow; j++) {
  for (var k = 1; k <= editColumn; k++){
    var formula = sheetToEdit.getRange(j,k).getFormula();
    var rowi= parseInt(formula.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''),10);
      if (rowi == row){
        if (k == column){
          sheetToEdit.getRange(j,k).setBackground('#faec15');          
        }
      };
  } 
}

}
```